# Meaning of this sentence: "I want the children to enjoy learning while creating a fun environment."

Tags: sentence-meaning

> I want the children to enjoy learning while creating a fun environment.

What does this sentence mean? Does it mean that the children should create the fun environment while learning or that I am creating the fun environment? I want it to mean that the children have enjoy learning in the fun environment that I created.

Answer (score 1):

A restatement of this sentence with the same meaning is "I want the children to enjoy learning while (either I and/or the children) create a fun environment (for them to do so in).

The original sentence implies the children enjoy learning in the created fun environment but not who created or made it fun (you or the children).